# Chrome Extension is being blocked by Etsy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, etsy

I'm trying to build a new chrome extension that adds a button to Etsy listing page.
The extension is unpacked, and once installed it works great on any site. however, whatever I tried - I'm not able to see the change on Etsy.

Here is the content script that runs:

```
document.body.appendChild( div );
div.appendChild( btnForm );
btnForm.appendChild( btn );
div.id = 'myDivId';
div.style.position = 'fixed';
div.style.top = '50%';
div.style.left = '50%';
div.style.width = '100%';
div.style.height = '100%';
div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Again, this works great on any other webpage I tested.
The permissions I'm using:

```
"permissions" : [
"declarativeContent",
"contextMenus",
"tabs",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*"
```

],

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifiest file look like

```
{
    "name": "SimplydevTranslator",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/bsmahala/",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "*://*/*", "tabs", "webNavigation", "activeTab"
    ], 
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "all_frames": true
    }],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

You code must be written in

// contentscript.js

```
function appendButton() {

 var div= document.createElement('div');
 var btnForm  = document.createElement('div');
 var btn = document.createElement('button');

 document.body.appendChild( div );
 div.appendChild( btnForm );
 btnForm.appendChild( btn );

 div.id = 'myDivId';
 div.style.position = 'fixed';
 div.style.top = '50%';
 div.style.left = '50%';
 div.style.width = '100%';
 div.style.height = '100%';
 div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

}


appendButton();
```